# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation, trying to ajax post data to method that returns json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

It is giving me the uncaught typeerror on the $.ajax({ line below.

```
function set_cookie(hashtag_data)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://domain.dev/home/set_cookie",
        data: { hashtag: hashtag_data },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                console.log(data.message);
            } else {
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
}

twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    $(event.target).closest('div').hide().next().show();

    set_cookie(event.target);
});
```

the home/set_cookie the ajax is suppose to post to returns a json encoded response with status and message.

```
// home/set_cookie, php function
public function set_cookie()
{
    $hashtag = "test";
    print json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $hashtag));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Does http://domain.dev/home/set_cookie expect that a JSON object gets sent to it?

Comment: If so, you might need to serialize your request body to JSON.

Comment: @JoshBeam it does not expect anything, just for testing, I print out a string in json format

Comment: Can you post the code that's in your home/set_cookie file?